# Mac mini FusionDrive - “No CoreStorage Logical Volume Groups Found”

Tags: catalina, disk-utility, mac-mini, fusion-drive, core-storage

I can't figure out how to correct this at this point. I’m hoping someone here can point me in the correct direction.

I have posted my terminal outputs below for `diskUtil list` and `diskUtil cs list`.

```
@MacMini ~ % diskUtil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:             TYPE NAME           SIZE     IDENTIFIER
   0:    GUID_partition_scheme             *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:             EFI EFI            209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_APFS Container disk2      121.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:             TYPE NAME           SIZE     IDENTIFIER
   0:    GUID_partition_scheme             *1.0 TB    disk1
   1:             EFI EFI            209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_APFS Container disk2      1000.0 GB  disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:             TYPE NAME           SIZE     IDENTIFIER
   0:    APFS Container Scheme -            +1.1 TB    disk2
                  Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
   1:         APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data    58.4 GB   disk2s1
   2:         APFS Volume Preboot          83.2 MB   disk2s2
   3:         APFS Volume Recovery         528.8 MB   disk2s3
   4:         APFS Volume VM            3.2 GB    disk2s4
   5:         APFS Volume Macintosh HD       11.0 GB   disk2s5

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:             TYPE NAME           SIZE     IDENTIFIER
   0:    GUID_partition_scheme             *8.0 TB    disk3
   1:             EFI EFI            209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:          Apple_HFS Adult Entertainment    2.0 TB    disk3s2
   3:          Apple_HFS Room4Activities      6.0 TB    disk3s3

@MacMini ~ % diskUtil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
@MacMini ~ %
```

Comment: I’m going to close this. You didn’t say if you wanted to erase the drive or install on one partition. What does an answer look like when you can fix your desired end state for this Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Once you're converted to APFS, CoreStorage is managed differently.

Your result for `diskutil list` correctly shows both internal physical drives & the synthesised drive the OS constructs from that.
Note that both parts of what used to be called only from `diskutil cs list` both reference the same Apple_APFS Container disk2, which is correct, & the construction is re-stated in the synthesized drive as `Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2`.
That it shows as Container disk2 rather than 1 means you have at some point re-formatted or reassigned, but that is of no import. Mine is up to Container disk7 on one drive these days.

`diskutil cs list` is now redundant.

There is a considerably more detailed explanation at [The Eclectic Light Company - Fusion Drives in APFS](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/10/15/fusion-drives-in-apfs/)

Comment: Thank You! I started down this path because I have been having rampant permissions issues. Even after having checked to make sure that I am the owner of my home folder, and I’ve applied that to all the enclosed files. My assumption was something had gone wrong with the drive. The “No CoreStorage” Message threw me for a loop. I cant even delete a file without being asked for a password to authorize.